# Android AIDL with annotations

Tags: android, aidl

I would like to use a custom annotation in order to include more code to the AIDL's generated code.

In the android documentation, [there is a reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) saying we can use annotations like `@nullable`, but when i add that annotation, it gives a compile error.

I would like to be able to have an AIDL function like the following:

```
interface AppcoinsBilling {
  @MyAnnotation String test();
}
```

Is that possible?

Are you guys able to use annotations in AIDL files?
Is there any other friendly way to change the generated code?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: In terms of the problem you are seeing now, try `@Nullable`. I have not used annotations in AIDL, as it would require both the client and the service to have a definition for the annotation.

Comment: It doesn't work. As soon as I insert the ```@``` it shows an error. I'm wondering if the documentation is wrong.

Comment: It's certainly possible -- there are a lot of documentation bugs. The standard annotation for this uses a capital `N`, which is why I was hoping that was the problem.

Comment: Well, i opened an issue on the documentation platform, I'll this post updated.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I also want and can't use `@nullable`, because `'@' unexpected`... (code: `@nullable User registerUser(String name)`

Comment: I ended up using other approach. At the time I opened [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131618219) issue, i'm not sure if you can open it. It was marked as obsolete.