# Annotations not recognized in AIDL file ('@' unexpected)

Tags: android, aidl

I have some simple AIDL, which can carry/return some custom parcelable model, lets call it `User`. This works without a problem, data is passed properly. Now I want to have option for returning `null`, e.g. in case when registration fails, so I'm placing `@nullable` at te beginning of line

```
@nullable User registerUser(String name);
```

and then I'm getting `'@' unexpected` error, it's not recognizing this annotation, in fact any annotation can't be placed... Do I have to import/enable somehow these annotations?

placing `@nullable` is suggested [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl#Create) (last point on "be aware that:" list), [HERE](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/aidl-annotations#nullable) and [HERE](https://source.android.google.cn/devices/architecture/aidl/aidl-backends?hl=en&authuser=0#nullability)

some sample from Android OS using `@nullable` (for arguments) in [HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/cmds/installd/binder/android/os/IInstalld.aidl), so this is possible and valid

very similar question in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904027/android-aidl-with-annotations) (without an answer :( )